# Whether the word 'me'or 'myself' is correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-case, objective-case

Should I use *me* or *myself* in this:

Happy teachers  day to all of us … and a special mention to those previously/  currently in the teaching profession….
Fattubhen, nishrin Bhen, Mehzabeen, Masuma Bhen and Dipti.

Also … **myself**.

In case I have forgotten anyone, please accept a sorry for that and special wish for you.

Comment: I think you'll need to clarify the question here, if there is one.

Comment: That's fine. *Myself* works well.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Samira Savliwala. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Considering the state the rest of the text is in, it simply does not matter. Choosing what word to put in that one blank is the least of the problems you are facing.

Comment: I find nothing wrong with the sentence in general. And it's actually a matter of choice if you want to use *me* or *myself*. They are both used so often in this situation that, regardless of strict analysis, it doesn't really matter. For instance, many people say *Happy Birthday to me*, while *Happy Birthday to myself* would sound strange. On the other hand, *I'm going to give a present to myself* is normal, while *I'm going to give a present to me* is odd. *Myself* may have a slight edge here, but it's minimal.

Comment: @JasonBassford The reason for "Happy Birthday to me" may simply be that it fits the meter of the song better.

Comment: The last sentence has some clumsiness. "accept a sorry" should be "accept my apology".